# How to implement an autoupdate on exe files

Tags: python, exe

I created an application and distributed it to people through an exe file, I would like this to be updated automatically every time I make changes. How can I do?

Comment: Did you uploaded your application to `github`?

Comment: i use Gitlab @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: That's not problem.How do people download your exe file?

Comment: I send him a download link using MEGA

Comment: `autoupdate`,you mean you want your exe download your latest version in the background?

Comment: no, without me sending the link of MEGA every time, the auto-update application when it is opened